How to distinguish between properties of a curve and properties of its individual parameterisations?
Suppose we have a curve $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This curve can have many different parameterisations $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \ldots$, etc. Since these are essentially different functions, one function may have a property which another function does not - in this case, I consider it a property of the parameterisation and not of the curve itself. However, some properties - for example, arc length - appear to be shared by all parameterisations due to the fact that they parameterise the same curve, i.e. if one parameterisation has this property, then all parameterisations have it. These I consider properties of the curve.
The problem is, however, that many textbooks do not make this distinction. They give a definition of what a curve is and what a curve parameterisation is, they usually state that parameterisations are not the same thing as the curve they parameterise and then proceed to completely ignore this distinction by tying every single proposition to a particular parameterisation. The simplest examples I can think of are arc length and scalar line integrals - every parameterisation of a curve yields the same value for the arc length / scalar line integral, which makes those properties of the curve and not of an individual parameterisation. But textbooks rarely mention this - they just pick a particular parameterisation $\gamma: [a;b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and define arc length as the integral of the norm of its derivative. This is, of course, bad because it ties the definition to a parameterisation and "disconnects" it from the bigger picture.
A consequence of this is that, at some point, these textbooks begin to define objects with a strictly geometric nature using a particular parameterisation - i.e. they no longer even bother making the distinction between a function and its image. For example, a path is often defined as a continuous function $\gamma: [a;b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ but in reality, a path is a geometric object - it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which "begins" at one point and "ends" at another. Intuitively, a path should be a curve, but the above definition makes it a curve parameterisation, i.e. it gives us a definition of what a path parameterisation is, but not of what a path is. And here we can, for example, ask whether every parameterisation of the same path has a closed interval as its domain. This distinction is important because, if not, then some propositions (those proven via a parameterisation of the form $\gamma: [a;b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$) turn out to be properties of particular parameterisations and not of the path itself despite often being presented as the latter.
Do you know of any vector analysis textbooks which treat such questions rigorously?
